# How to replace notes by icons

Tags: diagrams

Is it possible to place icons inside of each notes like the following ?

[image: Picture to icons]

Comment: Please provide the code relate to the question.

Comment: Please, provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140133).

Comment: When I look at the example, I see that the symbol indicates the hight / name of the note. If you want to use this often, maybe it is worth to define a nieuw kind of note head, like it is done for percussion, harmonic notes etc. (Have a look at the Musixdoc.pdf) You would need 14 note heads:seven with black background and seven open notes (there is no need to make a difference between a whole and a half note head). Before starting resizing images to fit in the lines, think about the purpose, maybe just a colored note head would be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

This, perhaps, can give an idea of what might be doable.  From studying the `\meaning` of `\zh`, I eventually deduced that the note is set with `\@ight`, which is given as `\char"8` in the musictex font.  Instead, I redefined the macro to stack a colored symbol from `\normalfont` atop the `\char"8` symbol, to achieve something akin to what is being asked.  One could alternately have chosen a small graphic to instead stack on the base note.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,10pt]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[english,dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{musixtex,stackengine,xcolor}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\setstackgap{L}{-1.6pt}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}
\setstaffs1{2}
\startpiece
\makeatletter
\def\@ight{\stackon{\char"8}{\color{red}\normalfont\scriptsize
   \kern6pt x}}%
\makeatother
  \notes \zh{ceg}|\zh{j} \en
  \notes \zh{fhj}|\zh{j} \en
  \notes \zh{gik}|\zh{k} \en
\makeatletter
\def\@ight{\stackon{\char"8}{\color{cyan}\normalfont\scriptsize
   \kern6pt w}}%
\makeatother
  \notes \zh{ceg}|\zh{l} \en
  \notes \zh{fhj}|\zh{m} \en
  \notes \zh{gik}|\zh{n} \en
\makeatletter
\def\@ight{\char"8}%
\makeatother
  \notes \zh{ceg}|\zh{n} \en
  \notes \zh{fhj}|\zh{o} \en
  \notes \zh{gik}|\zh{p} \en
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]